# Write STL file with voxel dimension Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, 3d, voxel

I have the following problem using Matlab: I have a binary volume and a 1x3 vector containing the voxel dimension and I want to write a STL file including the voxel dimension. From the binary image I use the isosurface command:  https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html in order to find faces and vertices and then I write the stl file using the stlwrite function:  https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20922-stlwrite-filename--varargin- . The problem is that in this workflow I cannot add the information of voxel dimension since the isosurface function considers the voxel as a ones vector. Do you have any idea of how I can write a STL file from a binary image including the information of voxel dimension?

Comment: the dimensions vector is for x,y and z axis right? what if you try to scale the model before or after you save it. you can use the `S = makehgtform('scale',[sx, sy, sz])` to create the matrix and then `newVertices = S*oldVertices`, the faces indexing should remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, the dimensions vector is for x, y and z axis. I've tried your solution and S results as a 4x4 matrix. The isosurface command creates a Nx3 matrix of faces and an Mx3 matrix of vertices. If I multiply the Mx3 matrix of vertices and the 4x4 S matrix, Matlab gives me an error: inner matrix dimensions must agree. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, that is because you have to transfer to  homogeneous coordinates (meaning `[ x, y, z]` turns into `[x,y,z,1]`). However if you only do scaling, then you can omit the last line and column of S and multiply that (the added 1 is for translation). 
so, to fix my code from earlier it would be `newVertices = S(1:3,1:3)*oldVertices`

Comment: Ok thank you vey very much! It works!